# Reversing the morphing animation from arrow to checkmark

Tags: android, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to achieve the morphing effect, when the user clicks myButton, the image inside the ImageView should morph from arrow to checkmark. And when he clicks it again, the process should reverse: the checkmark should morph to arrow.

This is what I have done:

animated_vector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/vector_upvote">

    <target
        android:name="rotationGroup"
        android:animation="@anim/rotate_a_to_b" />

    <target
        android:name="upvote"
        android:animation="@animator/animator_upvote_to_checkmark" />
</animated-vector>
```

animator_upvote_to_checkmark.xml:

```
<objectAnimator
    android:duration="250"
    android:propertyName="pathData"
    android:valueFrom="@string/svg_upvote"
    android:valueTo="@string/svg_checkmark"
    android:valueType="pathType"
    android:repeatMode="reverse" />
```

And this is how I play the animation:

```
            Drawable drawable = upVote.getDrawable();
            if (drawable instanceof Animatable) {

                ((Animatable) drawable).start();
            }
```

This morphs the arrow into checkmark, how do I reverse the process?

Answer (score 26):

if your view is `checkable` and also your `minsdk > 21` you can try using `StateListAnimator` with `AnimatedVectorDrawable` but because the `appcompat` now supports `vectorDrawable` and `AnimatedVectorDrawable` and also has a limitation on using all `DrawableContainers` I do not take above approach.

> So let me tell you what may work:
>
> DrawableContainers which reference other drawables resources which
>   contain only a vector resource. For example, a StateListDrawable which
>   references other files which contain a vector.

from [Chris Banes](https://chris.banes.me/2016/02/25/appcompat-vector/)

In order to achieve that I am going to create custom `ImageView` and every time it is clicked you must call `morph` function to run appropriate `vectorAnimatorDrawable`.

So code and demo:

[image]

```
public class ArrowToCheckMarkMorphingImageView extends ImageView {

    private AnimatedVectorDrawable mArrowToCheckMark;
    private AnimatedVectorDrawable mCheckMarkToArrow;
    private boolean mIsShowingCheckMark;
    public ArrowToCheckMarkMorphingImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ArrowToCheckMarkMorphingImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public ArrowToCheckMarkMorphingImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public ArrowToCheckMarkMorphingImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        mIsShowingCheckMark = false;
        mArrowToCheckMark =
                (AnimatedVectorDrawable)getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_to_checkmark);
        mCheckMarkToArrow =
                (AnimatedVectorDrawable)getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.checkmark_to_arrow);
        setImageDrawable(mArrowToCheckMark);
    }

    public void morph(){
        final AnimatedVectorDrawable drawable
                = mIsShowingCheckMark ? mCheckMarkToArrow : mArrowToCheckMark;
        setImageDrawable(drawable);
        drawable.start();
        mIsShowingCheckMark = !mIsShowingCheckMark;
    }

}
```

and `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrowToCheckMarkMorphingImageView mArrowToCheckMarkImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mArrowToCheckMarkImageView = (ArrowToCheckMarkMorphingImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mArrowToCheckMarkImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mArrowToCheckMarkImageView.morph();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

in layout file you must use it like:

```
  <yourpackage.ArrowToCheckMarkMorphingImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
```

and resources for those who wants to give it a try:

**res/animator/arrow_to_checkmark**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="pathData"
        android:valueFrom="M7.41,15.41 L12,10.83 l4.59,4.58 L18,14 18,14 l-6,-6 -6,6z"
        android:valueTo  ="M9,16.17 L4.83,12 l-1.42,1.41 L9,19 21,7 l-1.41,-1.41 0,0z"
        android:valueType="pathType" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="fillColor"
        android:valueFrom="#FF0000FF"
        android:valueTo="#FF00FF00" />
</set>
```

**res/animator/checkmark_to_arrow**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="pathData"
        android:valueFrom="M9,16.17 L4.83,12 l-1.42,1.41 L9,19 21,7 l-1.41,-1.41 0,0z"
        android:valueTo  ="M7.41,15.41 L12,10.83 l4.59,4.58 L18,14 18,14 l-6,-6 -6,6z"
        android:valueType="pathType" />
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="500"
        android:propertyName="fillColor"
        android:valueFrom="#FF00FF00"
        android:valueTo="#FF0000FF" />
</set>
```

**res/drawable/arrow_to_checkmark**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_up_24dp">
    <target
        android:animation="@animator/arrow_to_checkmark"
        android:name="arrow"/>
</animated-vector>
```

**res/drawable/checkmark_to_arrow**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkmark_24dp">
    <target
        android:animation="@animator/checkmark_to_arrow"
        android:name="checkmark"/>
</animated-vector>
```

**res/drawable/ic_arrow_up_24dp**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:name="arrow"
        android:fillColor="#FF0000FF"
        android:pathData="M7.41,15.41 L12,10.83 l4.59,4.58 L18,14 18,14 l-6,-6 -6,6z"/>
</vector>
```

**res/drawable/ic_checkmark_24dp**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:name="checkmark"
        android:fillColor="#FF00FF00"
        android:pathData="M9,16.17 L4.83,12 l-1.42,1.41 L9,19 21,7 l-1.41,-1.41 0,0z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation - In throws of doing this exact thing.  Seems to be a lot of effort i.e code/files for quite a basic animation!

Comment: @MarkKeen Just wanted to do this and the answer splits the code up in multiple files for structure, imho a little bit excessive, the code becomes a bit smaller if you do not split up animation xmls. The annotying thing by splitting is that you still have to duplicate the pathdata in the drawable and the animation

Answer (score 9):

I will go with Circular Progress Button, you can customize it based on your need or extend the library (since. it's open source). I have been using that for a while and it is pretty easy to integrate on your projects.

Also, you can learn from that and create your own library :-)

Here the Git repository
[CircularProgressButton](https://github.com/flavioarfaria/circular-progress-button)

[image]

Also, you can try out other excellent open source such as [Android Morphing Button](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-morphing-button)

[image]
[image]